# How can I create a collage in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to write a program that can create random collages from a given folder of pictures.

To begin, I want to create a simple collage from three images. Something like this:

[image]

I have almost no code right now

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

a = imread('a.png');
b = imread('b.png');
c = imread('c.png');

% create a new image of size X x Y

% for a simple collage

% place a in the top half
% place b in the bottom left
% place c in the bottom right
```

How can this be done in MATLAB?

---

How can I **stretch**, **rotate** and then place the individual images on a canvas, so that I can have the complete freedom while creating the collage? The image placement might so happen that the images lie outside the canvas area.

[image]

Stretching images to form is collage is one way, but I want to be able to stretch and place them

Comment: What size are the individual images? What if all the images are square?

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to stretch images into shape and that you have the image processing toolbox, you can do the collage the following way, using [IMRESIZE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imresize.html):

Create a function that you save as a .m file. This is much safer than calling clear all/close all

```
function collImg = collage 
%#COLLIMG creates a collage of three images called 'a.png' 'b.png' and 'c.png'
%#
%# OUTPUT collImg : collage image, with individual images arranged as [a;b,c]
%#

a = imread('a.png');
b = imread('b.png');
c = imread('c.png');

newImageSize = [512,512]; %# or anything else that is even

%# get the new sizes - this approach requires even image size
newSizeA = newImageSize./[2,1];
newSizeB = newImageSize./[2,2];
newSizeC = newImageSize./[2,2];

%# resize the images and stick together
%# place a in the top half
%# place b in the bottom left
%# place c in the bottom right 
collImg = [imresize(a,newSizeA);imresize(b,newSizeB),imresize(c,newSizeC)];

%# display the image
figure,imshow(collImg)
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, I can use the toolbox. I want to be able to place the images at any part of the canvas. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You first define the center point and the new size of each image. Then (in a loop) you resize the images, use `imrotate` to rotate them, and finally you place the image onto the collage so that the center is where you'd want it to be.